# log4j2 SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy creating files every minute

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I have a log4j2.xml with one of the appender like below :

```
        <RollingFile name="performance" 
            filePattern="/logs/myapp/myapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.perf.log"
            append="true">
            <Policies>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 * * * * ?" evaluateOnStartup="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/>                  
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
```

So the idea was to have crontrigger policy to create a new log file every day, but also set to rollover intraday when the file size reaches 500 MB.

But it results in a log file that gets created every minute like

> myapp.2018-05-10.1.perf.log
>
> myapp.2018-05-10.2.perf.log
>
> ...
>
> myapp.2018-05-10.121.perf.log

Not sure, what I am missing in here. Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your cron expression is wrong.

```
<RollingFile name="performance" 
        filePattern="/logs/myapp/myapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.perf.log"
        append="true">
        <Policies>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 12 1/1 * ? *" evaluateOnStartup="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/>                  
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

Here is the correct approch

```
<RollingFile name="performance" 
    filePattern="/logs/myapp/myapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.perf.log"
    append="true">
    <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

The appender is able to understand what time interval we’re referring to because of the pattern used for the file name, “app.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.%i.log.gz”, which implicitly sets a roll to occur every day and compresses the rolled file.

Comment: Well, I had  
<CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 * * * * ?" evaluateOnStartup="true"/> working just fine until for the past few months. 

Now, that I want to add size based rollover to my appender, the cron has to be changed ? not sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: When you are combining two policy  time and size then you do not need CronTriggeringPolicy (It may not work).So I corrected the answer and it will work as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

well, I used the latest approach removing crontriggering policy and it didn't seem to work. For instance, May13 log files, were written to myapp.2018.05.12.2.perf.log and May14 log files, were written to 
myapp.2018.05.13.1.perf.log files

```
-rw-r--r-- app app  57329 May 12 23:56 myapp.2018.05.12.1.perf.log
-rw-r--r-- app app 335745 May 13 23:56 myapp.2018.05.12.2.perf.log
-rw-r--r-- app app 515998 May 14 07:55 myapp.2018.05.13.1.perf.log
```

Comment: Seems your original requirement (Time and Size) seems to be working as per your expectation. Regarding date mismatch issue , it is because of the version that you are using please follow the bug and upgrade the version as per the thread.Hope it will work
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-116